# negative margin-top is not working in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am working on a project and I have an issue with Firefox, I cant figure out what the problem is. I am new to HTML and CSS.

The link to the website is http://parapentemontanita.com/

In all browsers except IE and Firefox it works perfectly.
My problem is the section that says "VUELOS DE PARAPENTE TANDEM" who's class is tandem. The margin-top: -350px is not working.

```
.tandem
{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -350px !important;

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is because of styling of above blocks.
You have three blocks with classes `col-md-4 col-xs-12` and block with class `box_index` within each of them. These `col-md-4 col-xs-12` are floats and there is `clear:both;` in `::after` pseudo-element.

`box_index` block inside `col-md-4 col-xs-12` has declaration of `top:-290px;`. So content is moving up 290px but the container `col-md-4 col-xs-12` holds its calculated height. And because of clear, next content starts after they ended. You forcibly move next container upwards, but inner elements of the container are floats and obey the `clear:both;` rule. So you need to move them also.

But it would be better to change `top` to `margin-top:-290px;`.

And you do not need `margin-top:-350px` for `section.tandem` any more.

P.S. Tested in firefox 44 but I think will work in Chrome also.

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot.   :D

Answer (score 0):

Your `margin-top:-350px` positioning works without `!important`, so please don't use the important. Only if you have to overwrite an automaticaly generated inline style you're not able to delete. Otherwise you get more and more and more ... problems and work with the `!important` in your CSS.

In your cases:

You have a mess of negativ positionings in your layout... It's ok, but you have the wrong positioning type. You use `relative`, but you have to use an `absolute` positioning.

`absolute`: the elements height and width isn't in the normal content flow

`relative`: the elements height and width is in the normal content flow and takes it dimensions

Let us take the element `id="tandem"`, give them an outline like the bottom, so you see the real height of the element:

```
#tandem { 
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

outlineing the container of #tandem:
.col-md-4.col-xs-12 {
   outline: 1px solid yellow;
}

and the header
#tandem header {
   outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

On the picture you can see the real height of the element in Firefox:

[image]

I have done a lot of repositioning in Firebug to get the result below. I have set every `realtive` positioned element in `#tandem` etc. to `absolute`. Changed some nagative top positionings. You have to play a bit with it, but the keyword is `absolute` ;-)

[image]

At least a small hint, please optimize your images. At the moment you have a **page-weight from over 12MB** in desktop and mobile, the pictures of the small sliders are fullhd, scale them down and save as `.jpg`.

Every person with a slow mobile connection will be thankfull ;-)

[image]

Comment: Yes I am going to do that but I am supposed to wait for new photos.